# Poll on BPF device descriptor

Tags: c, macos, file-descriptor, polling, bpf

In my macOS (Sonoma 14.3) program, I'm hand-crafting a packet filter instead of using libpcap:

```c
int
create_filter(const char *device, struct bpf_insn *instructions, unsigned int num_instructions) {
    int fd, flags;
    unsigned int immediate = 1;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct bpf_program prog = {
        .bf_insns = instructions,
        .bf_len = num_instructions,
    };

    for (int k=0; k<256; k++) {
        char device[15];

        snprintf(device, sizeof(device), "/dev/bpf%i", k);
        fd = open(device, O_RDONLY);
        if ( fd < 0 ) {
            if ( errno == EBUSY ) {
                continue;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        break;
    }

    if ( fd < 0 ) {
        return -1;
    }

    snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name), "%s", device);
    if ( ioctl(fd, BIOCSETIF, &ifr) == -1 ) {
        goto error;
    }

    if ( ioctl(fd, BIOCIMMEDIATE, &immediate) == -1 ) {
        goto error;
    }

    if ( ioctl(fd, BIOCSETF, &prog) == -1 ) {
        goto error;
    }

    if ( (flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)) == -1 || fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) == -1 ) {
        goto error;
    }

    return fd;

error:
    close(fd);
    return -1;
}
```

This function works just fine.  I'm able to create the BPF and read and parse packets from the descriptor with `read`.  However, when I try to use `poll`:

```c
struct pollfd poller = {.fd = fd, .events = POLLIN};

poll(&poller, 1, -1); // Omitting error checking for brevity's sake.
```

`poller.revents` comes back as `POLLNVAL`.  The [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/poll.2.html) describes this value as meaning

> The file descriptor is not open.

I've confirmed that I'm not closing my descriptor anywhere before `poll` is called.  Why can't I `poll` the descriptor?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19836050/8075540) seems relevant except that I'm already following its advice.  That is, I've put the socket in non-blocking mode and set capture to be immediate.

To replicate this, you can use

```c
struct bpf_insn filter[] = {
    BPF_STMT(BPF_LD + BPF_W + BPF_LEN, 0),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_A, 0),
};
```

for the filter.